# New size of root partition doesn't seem to be recognized

Tags: root, disk-usage, cleanup

I ran out of space on my 20 GB root partition, I resized it to 32GB in gparted but it didn't seem to have created more free space.

I ran apt-get autoremove and apt-get autoclean, ran bleachbit as well as update-grub. Even though there should be 12 free GB on /root it's 94% full. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "seem to".  We need real numbers here.  Try adding the output of `df -h` and `parted -l` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install deborphan
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: Package 'deborphan' has no installation candidate
It seems it's not supported under 14.10.

Comment: Test your file /etc/apt/sources.list deborphan: http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deborphan/deborphan_1.7.28.8ubuntu1_amd64.deb and http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/deborphan/deborphan_1.7.28.8ubuntu1_i386.deb

Comment: It freed up some MB but nothing of significance. Thanks though.